# Im new to HTML, struggling with an email signature

Tags: html, email, html-table

I have been asked to create a HTML email signature, all looks fine in Google Chrome. But when viewed in Outlook, everything moves around.

Would anyone be able to shine some light on where I might be going wrong?

Thanks.

```html
<table aria-hidden="false" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" border="0px" width="350px" style="margin: 0px; max-width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" align="left" style="vertical-align:center">
      <a href="[https://www.bbc.com](https://www.bbc.com)">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0111/7877/0495/files/Tom_Avatar.png?v=1602754752" width="200px" style="padding-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;" />
      </a>
    </td>

    <td colspan="2" align="center" style="vertical-align:bottom">
      <a href="[https://www.bbc.com](https://www.bbc.com)">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0111/7877/0495/files/Lixi_Logo_6fa83943-d431-41b8-acd1-4e1180dc1aa1.png?v=1602754752" width="125px" style="padding-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <a href="[https://www.facebook.com/](https://www.facebook.com/)">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0111/7877/0495/files/Face.png?v=1602680973" width="50px" style="padding-left: 15px;" />
      </a>
    </td>

    <td align="center">
      <a href="[https://www.instagram.com/](https://www.instagram.com/)">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0111/7877/0495/files/InstaG.png?v=1602680973" width="50px" style="padding-right: 15px;" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <td valign="top">
    <p style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #464646; margin: 0px; padding-top: 30px; padding-left: 30px;">
      <strong>This Guy</strong><br />
      <strong>Job title</strong><br /><br />
      <strong>e: </strong><a href="mailto: [thisguy@email.com](mailto:thisguy@email.com)" target="\_blank" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">thisguy@email.com</a><br />
      <strong>w: </strong><a href="[www.bbc.com](https://www.bbc.com)" target="\_blank" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">www.bbc.com</a><br />
    </p>
  </td>
</table>
```

Comment: Start by validating your HTML. Far too much deprecated attributes that belong in CSS and the last row is not  a row

Answer (score 0):

Your document was [not valid](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

- remove deprecated attributes and add the correct CSS in the style tags
- last cell was not in a row and was too narrow (colspan)
- missing ALT tags on images (not super important)
- hyperlinks were not correct (BBCode or markdown)
- No need to make all lines "strong" in a set of lines.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <table aria-hidden="false" style="width:350px; padding: 0; border:0; margin: 0px; max-width: 100%;">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:center">
        <a href="https://www.bbc.com/">
          <img alt="avatar" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0111/7877/0495/files/Tom_Avatar.png?v=1602754752" style="width:200px;padding-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;" />
        </a>
      </td>

      <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center; vertical-align:bottom">
        <a href="https://www.bbc.com/">
          <img alt="logo" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0111/7877/0495/files/Lixi_Logo_6fa83943-d431-41b8-acd1-4e1180dc1aa1.png?v=1602754752" style="width:125px; padding-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;" />
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
          <img alt="facebook" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0111/7877/0495/files/Face.png?v=1602680973" style="width:50px;padding-left: 15px;" />
        </a>
      </td>

      <td style="text-align:center">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/">
          <img alt="instagram" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0111/7877/0495/files/InstaG.png?v=1602680973" style="width:50px;padding-right: 15px;" />
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="vertical-align:top">
        <p style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #464646; margin: 0px; padding-top: 30px; padding-left: 30px;">
          <strong>This Guy<br />
          Job title<br /><br />
          e: </strong><a href="mailto:thisguy@email.com" target="\_blank" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">thisguy@email.com</a><br />
          <strong>w: </strong><a href="https://www.bbc.com" target="\_blank" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">www.bbc.com</a><br />
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the advice, I have tried your code.

It looks good on the browser but when applied to the outlook signature, everything increases in size drastically apart from the text.

I have no idea why this would be, do you?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the incomplete structure of the HTML `table` in your code. To make your table *complete*, you need to wrap a `tr` around your last `td` to create  a third row and apply `colspan="3"`to that last `td` to make it span the whole row.

Some browsers probably tolerate the missing elements, trying to fix the given code automatically, but others won't, which is what you experienced.

```html
<table aria-hidden="false" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" border="0px" width="350px" style="margin: 0px; max-width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" align="left" style="vertical-align:center">
      <a href="[https://www.bbc.com](https://www.bbc.com)">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0111/7877/0495/files/Tom_Avatar.png?v=1602754752" width="200px" style="padding-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;" />
      </a>
    </td>

    <td colspan="2" align="center" style="vertical-align:bottom">
      <a href="[https://www.bbc.com](https://www.bbc.com)">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0111/7877/0495/files/Lixi_Logo_6fa83943-d431-41b8-acd1-4e1180dc1aa1.png?v=1602754752" width="125px" style="padding-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <a href="[https://www.facebook.com/](https://www.facebook.com/)">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0111/7877/0495/files/Face.png?v=1602680973" width="50px" style="padding-left: 15px;" />
      </a>
    </td>

    <td align="center">
      <a href="[https://www.instagram.com/](https://www.instagram.com/)">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0111/7877/0495/files/InstaG.png?v=1602680973" width="50px" style="padding-right: 15px;" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" colspan="3">
      <p style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #464646; margin: 0px; padding-top: 30px; padding-left: 30px;">
        <strong>This Guy</strong><br />
        <strong>Job title</strong><br /><br />
        <strong>e: </strong><a href="mailto: [thisguy@email.com](mailto:thisguy@email.com)" target="\_blank" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">thisguy@email.com</a><br />
        <strong>w: </strong><a href="[www.bbc.com](https://www.bbc.com)" target="\_blank" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">www.bbc.com</a><br />
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```